# robots.txt returns 404, Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 site hosted on webfusion.co.uk

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I have a hosting account with webfusion.co.uk where I host a few websites. I have uploaded a robots.txt file and a sitemap.xml file. when I try visiting them: www.ledflexi.co.uk/robots.txt or www.ledflexi.co.uk/sitemap.xml. The site returns a 404 error.

I have uploaded both files to the root folder of each site  (public_html/led-flex.co.uk)

Could the following lines of the .htaccess file be related to this problem?

```
############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides  
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all



########################Redirection############################
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the file name, in linux servers if the name is not in the exact case that you have typed. it will return 404. make sure the filename is 'robots.txt' (all small case)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vilsad for replying to the question.

I found the problem, and though I'm a bit ebarrassed by it here it is: I was Uploading to the wrong accound : "led-flex.co.uk" instead of "ledflexi.co.uk".

What a Klutz!